# Regex for removing spaces between start and end quote (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove spaces if they are shown on start or end of a name inside qotes. Let me explain more on example:

This is the result i have:
" HAIRDRESSER PERSON 1" Person one businesses
 
" HAIR STUDIO " Person two S.P.
" HAIRDRESSER PERSON 3     " - PERSON 3 S.P.

And this is what i'm trying to achieve:
"HAIRDRESSER PERSON 1" Person one businesses
 
"HAIR STUDIO" Person two S.P.
"HAIRDRESSER PERSON 3" - PERSON 3 S.P.

This is the code i'm working on:

```
$data[$num]['title'] = preg_replace(????????, "",$row->find('td',1)->plaintext);
```

If you have any better solution then preg_replace i'm open for it.
Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Can you please use the `code` tag (the image with the curly braces) to show us what you have and what you are trying to achieve? You have a lot of `<br>` and `&nbsp;` tags in your question which I am not sure if you added them for formatting purposes or if they are actually there/

Comment: To improve your question, please add a description of what is wrong with your current solution, does it create wrong output, does it throw any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't safe to only search quoted text that need to be trimmed (for example: `"abcd" efgh " ijkl "` can be problematic with this approach and a naive pattern).

A possible way consists to search *all* quoted parts and to trim them using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$data[$num]['title'] = preg_replace_callback('~"([^"]*)"~', function ($m) {
    return '"' . trim($m[1]) . '"'; }, $row->find('td', 1)->plaintext);
```

The advantage of this way is that the pattern used is very simple.

You can also avoid `preg_replace_callback` but you need a more complicated pattern:

```
$data[$num]['title'] = preg_replace('~"\s*+([^\s"]*(?:\s+[^\s"]+)*+)\s*"~', '"$1"', $row->find('td', 1)->plaintext);
```

Note that these two patterns assume that quotes are balanced and that quoted parts don't contain escaped quotes.

Comment: Second one did it for me!
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use `preg_replace` or `preg_replace_callback` with the `trim` function.

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~"(.*?)"~', function($matches) {
                                    return '"' . trim($matches[1]) . '"';
                            }, '"HAIRDRESSER PERSON 1" Person one businesses');
```

Output:

> "HAIRDRESSER PERSON 1" Person one businesses

```
echo preg_replace('~"\h*(.*?)\h*"~', '"$1"', '"HAIRDRESSER PERSON 1" Person one businesses');
```

Output:

> "HAIRDRESSER PERSON 1" Person one businesses

The `\h*` is any amount of horizontal whitespace between the `"` and the next `"`. Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/mG2eG9/1

The `preg_replace_callback` probably isn't needed here unless you wanted to manipulate the quoted data further.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following reg expression in javascript and it works

```
 replace(/(\"\s+)|(\s+\")/g,"\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$strings = array
(
    '" HAIRDRESSER PERSON 1" Person one businesses',
    '" HAIR STUDIO " Person two S.P.',
    '" HAIRDRESSER PERSON 3     " - PERSON 3 S.P'
);

foreach($strings as $string) {
    var_dump($string);
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/"(.*)"/i', function($match) { return sprintf('"%s"', trim($match[1])); }, $string);
    var_dump($string);
}
```

Returns

```
string '" HAIRDRESSER PERSON 1" Person one businesses' (length=45)
string '"HAIRDRESSER PERSON 1" Person one businesses' (length=44)
string '" HAIR STUDIO " Person two S.P.' (length=31)
string '"HAIR STUDIO" Person two S.P.' (length=29)
string '" HAIRDRESSER PERSON 3     " - PERSON 3 S.P' (length=43)
string '"HAIRDRESSER PERSON 3" - PERSON 3 S.P' (length=37)
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution you are trick it.

```
  str_replace('" ','"',$string);
```